# ArcGIS API for JavaScript: Draw a Tracker Line from GPS points

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tracking

I have gps points which sent from tacker device I need to draw a line in openstreet map ArcGIS with Javascript, How can I do this. I can convert gps points to any format that needs to be (XML, JSON, GPX...) and I have time with lat and lon if needed.

I am new with ArcGIS API for Javascript.

```
34.673876,68.790897
34.673876,68.790897
34.673876,68.790897
34.673876,68.790897
34.673876,68.790897
```

I want something like this but ArcGIS its google:

http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/EPM6A/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, create a polyline

```
 var polyline = new Polyline(new SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
```

after define path array,

```
var path = []
path.push(new Point(34.673876,68.790897));
path.push(new Point(34.673876,68.790897));
path.push(new Point(34.673876,68.790897));
path.push(new Point(34.673876,68.790897));
path.push(new Point(34.673876,68.790897));
```

and finally add path to polyline

```
polyline.addPath(path);
//add to map
map.graphics.add(new Graphic(polyline,new SimpleLineSymbol());
```

Comment: init.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polyline is not defined, I got this error from javascript debugger

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nasersobhan/pfbf0jvm/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfbf0jvm/2/ update your code its work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[https://jsfiddle.net/e7k5cykL/](https://jsfiddle.net/e7k5cykL/<br)

you can find other documentation here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/

Comment: can't open the first link, and the second it's not what I wanted.

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/lele3p/p8z075ce/